# Fix check box column to first position in ultragrid

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have an `ultragrid` with several columns that are fetched from the database. I have added A new `checkbox` column and I want it to be fixed in the first position, so that when I scroll the grid horizontally all columns move except the checkbox one. I have tried fix header and allow column moving property but its not helping me out.

Comment: Are you adding this column at runtime or design time?

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 5):

Without posting your code its tough to give you an exact answer, but you can do something like this:

```
private void yourUltraGrid_InitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Layout.UseFixedHeaders = true;
        e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns[0].Header.Fixed = true;
    }
```

And to make it so that it cannot be altered again. Use

```
this.yourUltraGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Override.FixedHeaderIndicator = FixedHeaderIndicator.None;
```